# SQL Server Bit Logic Operations - Need Some Help

Tags: sql-server

Say I have the following:

```
Declare @LineA int
Declare @LineB int
Declare @LineC int
Declare @LineD int
Declare @LineRequested int
Declare @LineTaken int

Set @LineA = 1
Set @LineB = 2
Set @LineC = 4
Set @LineD = 8

Set @LineRequested = 11 -- @LineA | @LineB | @LineD

Set @LineTaken = 2 -- Matches a line in @LineRequested (@LineB)
Set @LineTaken = 4 -- Does not match (Line C was not one of the lines OR'd)
```

How can I test to see if the value in @LineTaken makes up **ONE** of the values in @LineRequested? In my example above, when @LineTaken = 2, it does match one of the values (@LineA | @LineB). But, in the second, it does not. How can I programatically determine this?

Comment: Is `@LineTaken` always a power of 2? Are you always looking for a single line? If not what should happen when `@LineTaken` is 5 for example? You would want to match if **both** 1 and 4 are matched or if either of them match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @LineRequested | 2 = @LineRequested THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'  END,
       CASE WHEN @LineRequested | 4 = @LineRequested THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'  END
```

Comment: @Dumitrescu, don't sweat about it. It would have fooled me. I only looked closer because of your comment. *+1 to both solutions btw, afaik, they both seem correct to me*

Comment: @Lieven - They are different if `@LineTaken` is not an exact power of 2. My answer would return `Y` only if all bits set in `@LineTaken` were also set in `@LineRequested`. Dumitrescu's answer if at least one bit matches. That may be what is required from the bolded **one** in the text but the example given doesn't clarify this point...

Comment: I see. Doesn't that mean that both answers could be combined into `SELECT CASE WHEN @LineRequested & @LineTaken = @LineTaken THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END` for OP's given scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @LineRequested & @LineTaken > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
```